# What is the best way to refactor a Ruby ‘if’ statement into one-line shorthand form in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have the following Ruby code:

```
if some_cond && another
  foo_bar
end
```

and I want to change it to:

```
foo_bar if some_cond && another
```

What are the most idiomatic ways to do that in Vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the cursor is located at the `if`-line prior to
refactoring (not necessarily at the beginning of that line),
I would use the following sequence of Normal-mode commands:

```
ddjVpkJ<<
```

or this chain of Ex commands:

```
:m+|-j|<|+d
```

Here the `if`-line is first moved down one line by the `:move +` command.
The `:move` command cuts a given range of lines (the current line, if
not specified) and pastes it below the line addressed by the argument.
The `+` address is a shorthand for `.+1` referring to the next line
(see `:help {address}`).

Second, the line containing the body of the conditional statement is
joined with the just moved `if`-line. The `:join` command concatenates
a given range of lines into a single line. The `-` range is a shortened
form of the `.-1` address referring to the line just above the cursor
(see `:help {address}`).

Third, the newly joined line is unindented by one `shiftwidth` using
the `:<` command.

Finally, the remaining `end`-line, which can now be addressed as `+`,
is removed by the `:delete` command.

Comment: @ib Nice ex-command. I was think of some `:s//`, but that is much nicer, I may map that myself.

Comment: Ex commands You provided are awesome, but could You explain them and how to get help for them?

Comment: @Peter:  Thanks!  Something like `:s/^\s*\(if .*\)\n\(\_.*\)\n\s*end\>/\2 \1/|<` also works well enough.

Comment: @Sławosz:  Sure.  I've added a brief explanation of the actions behind that chain of the four Ex commands.  For further details see `:h :m`, `:h :j`, `:h :<`, `:h :d`, `:h {ad`.

Answer (score 2):

I see few (probably non-optimal) solutions:

1. cursor in first character in first line:

   - <kbd>D</kbd> - remove `if` condition but leave cursor in same position (don't delete line)
   - <kbd>J</kbd> - join next line to current
   - <kbd>A <Space> <ESC></kbd> - append space and exit to Normal mode
   - <kbd>p</kbd> - paste `if` condition
   - and then remove remaining end with <kbd>jdd</kbd>
2. cursor in first character in first line, as previously:

   - <kbd>j</kbd> - move to next line
   - <kbd>dd</kbd> - remove this line
   - <kbd>k</kbd> - move back to `if` condition
   - <kbd>P</kbd> - paste removed line before actual line, cursor should be placed to pasted line
   - <kbd>J</kbd> - join next line to current
   - <kbd>==</kbd> or <kbd><<</kbd> - unindent current line
   - and then remove remaining end with <kbd>jdd</kbd>
3. another solution:

   - <kbd>j</kbd> - move to second line
   - <kbd>J</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> - join line with next, remove what was joined
   - <kbd>dd</kbd> - remove current line
   - <kbd>k</kbd> - step to previous line
   - <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd><<</kbd> - paste, join and unshift

It's probably not optimal, but I do it without thinking, because most of this commands are in my muscle memory (you don't think how to move around you, how to yank/delete and paste most of the time, and joining line is also helpful to remember).

If you have `virtualedit` enabled in config, instead of <kbd>A <Space> <Esc></kbd> you can <kbd>$ <Space></kbd>, but I find <kbd>$</kbd> harder to use than <kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl-[</kbd> (it's simmilar to ESC).

As an advice: if you use some upper letter commands, try to chain them if it's possible, so you only need to keep Shift pressed and then execute some commands, instead of mixing upper and lower letter commands and pressing two keys at a time (upper letter is 2 key press, one is Shift). Once I found combo helpful for restarting server in console Ctrl+cpj, which sends Ctrl+c, Ctrl+p (previous command) and Ctrl+j (Enter key) with single Ctrl press. Since then I try to find simmilar time-saving combination in Vim too mostly with Shift, as Ctrl is not much used in Vim.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
ddpkJjdd
```

- <kbd>ddp</kbd> swap the two lines
- <kbd>kJ</kbd>  move up and join the lines
- <kbd>==</kbd> re-indent the line
- <kbd>jdd</kbd> move down and delete the last line

Answer (score 1):

There are probably 30 ways to do this.

Here is one, assuming you are starting from the end of the word `end` in normal mode:

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> (delete last line)
<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (delete and copy `foo_bar` to buffer `a`)
<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> (delete now-empty line 2)
<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (paste from buffer `a` before caret)
<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> (insert space and return to normal mode)

Again, "properly" rarely applies in Vim because there are so many ways to accomplish something. This is so small a change that even re-typing `foo_bar` could be justifiable.